# Different results with similar Entity Framework queries

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have a strange situation here that I'm just looking to understand a little better.  I'm using Entity Framework 6 in a project that I am maintaining as I update, and I cam across this query that is causing a timeout exception.

The underlying structure:

1. `[Orders]` - a table containing order-related data.
2. `[SearchOrders]` - a view containing an Id column and a searchable text column.
3. A table-valued function defined as:

   ```
   select r.[key] 
   from containstable(SearchOrders, *, @searchPhrase) as r
   ```

The environment is ASP.NET MVC 5 with a SQL Server database.

I have an `IQueryable<Order>` object stored in a variable, call it `results`.

If I execute the following line, I wait for a few seconds and receive a SQL timeout exception:

```
var orderIdsToReturn = results.Select(x => x.Id).ToArray();
return db.Orders.Where(x => orderIdsToReturn.Contains(x.Id));
```

However, if I execute this code, the desired output is realized:

```
var ordersToReturn = results.ToArray();
var orderIdsToReturn = ordersToReturn.Select(x => x.Id);
return db.Orders.Where(x => x.orderIdsToReturn.Contains(x.Id));
```

In both situations, I have an `IQueryable<Order>` object, which is then selecting the ID properties into an integer array, and then using that integer array to return the actual objects. The return lines are irrelevant, but I included them in the example for completeness.

The SQL timeout exception is occurring on the first line of the first example.

I'm not sure if there is any relevance to the "SearchOrders" (View) or the Table-Valued Function in regards to the situation because, at the time that the exception occurs I am only dealing with the `IQueryable<Order>` object, though I feel like some of the underlying issue may be caused by the source `Order` elements and how they are mapped underneath the hood.

Comment: `orderIdsToReturn` != `x.orderIdsToReturn`. Is it typo?

Comment: Change Tracking is enabled or disabled?

Comment: Change Tracking is enabled.